# Firefox on Windows 7 displays fonts on web pages in strange way

Tags: firefox, windows-7

Firefox keeps showing me text in font size I didn't set in css . In IE6 ,7 ,8 and in Chrome text has proper size, but in FF it's bigger. I use font-size: 10pt in css , in one place I put font-size property , html is valid , css is valid . This only happens under Windows 7 . http://tommymedical.pl

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you haven't accidentally set the zoom in Firefox?  It remembers the setting by site, so it would end up showing up zoomed each time.  Press Ctrl+0 to reset.  Firefox is working as expected in Win7 for me, so I think it may be something else, or something specific to your system with FF+Win7.

Comment: I did that , sorry I forget to tell that

Comment: Perhaps use the DOM Inspector (Ctrl+Shift+I) to see what styles may be getting applied for your elements, and where those styles may be coming from.